# Self deployable Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, websphere, ear

How to make a Java EE application to replace its EAR and restart without accessing server console?
It is running in IBM Websphere 6.

**2012-02-08: Added**

I'm not able to run scripts on server because it is a shared host. The only thing I can do is to rebuild the application and ask permission to publish. It's a long and burocratic process. So I would like to make it self deployable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wsadmin scripting facilities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/welc6topscripting.html) to do this. Integrate that with your build tools like Ant or Maven etc.

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans IDE has a feature "Deploy on save" for a java ee application. However I am not sure if you can register a Websphere server in order for your application to be deplyed automatically. Another option, since i am working with Glassfish server, is to copy the ear file to the autodeploy folder and the application is being redeployed. I dont know if websphere has a similar feature. I hope i gave you some options. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Continous Integration Server like Jenkins/Hudson, it will build and deploy your code without manual intervention, once you configure it. you can use ant or maven as your build tools.

You can use Continous integration with any web-server or application server.